# How to return a static file as a response in spark-java? (not redirect)

Tags: java, spark-java

I need to return a content of static html file as a response, for example, if the user is trying to get to `localhost:4567/hello.html`, I want to show another html file instead of `hello.html` that says he does not have permissions to see this page.

Now I am redirecting to the page:

```
private void securityFilter(Request request, Response response) {
    if (notAuthorized) {
        response.redirect("/Error/AccessDenied.html");
    }
}
```

But I do not want to redirect the user, I want to return a response with status code `401` and with a static file as a response content.

Thanks.

Comment: please refer the answer in the below link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34197544/how-to-return-a-static-html-page-with-spark-java/34220688

Comment: @NareshBatthula this answer is not what I need. I know how to redirect to a static file but I need to send it's content as a response instead.

Answer (score 1):

> But I do not want to redirect the user, I want to return a response with status code 401 and with a static file as a response content.

Then you need to read the HTML file as a String and set it as the response body.

```
private void securityFilter(Request request, Response response) {
    if (notAuthorized) {
        response.body(/* read HTML file as string */);
    }
}
```

Comment: As it might work, I am looking for a solution that uses Spark's `StaticFilesConfiguration` or something else like that. For example, Express.JS uses `response.sendFile()`.

Comment: That's not an option in Spark (only with a redirect).